# Ajax call to .asmx page method failing with invalid System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, invalidoperationexception

I am trying to use a jquery autocomplete with an ajax call to a webservice method the call works fine on localhost but when published to the dev server it fails everytime and using google chrome to debug i get the following error:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: sLookUP.
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()    
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

I am using **ASP.NET3.5** with **IIS 7.5** where as the dev machine is **IIS 6** with **ASP.NET 2.0**

My ajax call is as follows:

```
        $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url: "Address.asmx/ShowAddress",
                data: "{ 'sLookUP': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
```

My webmethod in Address.asmx :

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public String[] ShowAddress(string sLookUP)
    {
        List<string> lstAddresses = new List<string>();

        DataTable dtAddresses;
        Address Addr = new Address();
        dtAddresses = Addr.GetLookupAddresses(sLookUP);


        foreach (DataRow row in dtAddresses.Rows)
        {
            lstAddresses.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}-{8}", row["OrderAddress_name"], row["OrderAddress_id"], row["OrderAddress_1"], row["OrderAddress_2"], row["OrderAddress_town"], row["OrderAddress_county"], row["OrderAddress_postcode"], row["OrderAddress_fulladdress"],row["OrderAddress_ClusterID"]));
        }
        return lstAddresses.ToArray();
    }
```

web.config settings (there's been suggestions on other questions these should help:

```
<webServices>

      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="Documentation"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>




<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Any suggestion welcome I've tried so many things but as it works on my machine i'm thinking its an iis/web.config setting I've missed or written incorrectly because the dev machine has a different setup. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the attribute `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` to your asmx service declaration. When you add the asmx to your solution, Visual Studio creates your service body with this attribute but commented. See example below.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Address : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public String[] ShowAddress(string sLookUP)
    {
        List<string> lstAddresses = new List<string>();

        // YOUR CODE GO HERE

        return lstAddresses.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have included more of my code . Thats already included I think it has to do with ASP.NET 2.0 on the dev machine. Thanks for replying.